# Is it defined behaviour to assign to function call in or in if (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior

During a codebase refactor I found code like this:

```cpp
void myFunction (std::map<int, int> my_map)
{
    int linked_element;
    if (my_map[linked_element = firstIndex] != 0
        || my_map[linked_element = secondIndex] != 0)
    {
        // do some stuff with linked_element
    }
}
```

Or

```cpp
void myFunction (std::set<int> my_set)
{
    int linked_element;
    if (my_set.find(linked_element = firstIndex) != my_set.end()
        || my_set.find(linked_element = secondIndex) != my_set.end())
    {
        // do some stuff with linked_element
    }
}
```

From what I understood the aim of that was to avoid checking 2 times (first when entering in the if, second when assigning the variable).
I can understand that depending on which side of the `||` is true linked_element will be assigned to the right value but this still feels kind of bad to me.

Is this kind of behaviour defined?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am having a strange behaviour on the function (1k+ lines function) this code is in when compiling on MSVC with compiler optimizations enabled. The code is so dense that I can't debug it properly and this piece of code is something that I am not used to see and that feels really strange to me (there are others really bad stuff but they don't look as strange to me)

Comment: Very lot of odd things are well defined in C++, this included. If the way how these are defined confuses then it is still better to avoid using those if possible.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes you're right, it is a set not a vector. Fixed it.

Comment: *Every value computation and side effect of the first (left) argument of the built-in logical AND operator && and the built-in logical OR operator || is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of the second (right) argument.* (since C++11)

Comment: And *Builtin operators && and || perform short-circuit evaluation (do not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating the first)*

Comment: I've got a problem parsing the title. "assign to function call"? If the function _returns_ an rvalue, you can assign to that rvalue. But that's not what happens here. This is an assignment expression inside a larger expression - entirely legal, though a bit unusual.

Comment: @MSalters Agree, I think somethink like "Is it defined behaviour to assign different value to same variable in different operands of builtin OR operator (C++17)"

Comment: I suppose I’m the only one who doesn’t find this the least bit difficult to read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is well defined by the order of evaluation.

First, the `linked_element = firstIndex` assignment happens. This expression returns the value of `firstIndex`, that is then used as an argument for the subscript operator on `my_map` (i.e., `my_map[linked_element = firstIndex]`). The return value from that expression is checked against the `!= 0` condition. If it's true, the other side of the `||` operator is not evaluated due to short-circuit logic. If it's false, the same story happens on the other side of the operator.

Whether or not it's a good practice to write code in such a style is a different question though. Personally speaking, I'd prioritize readability and maintainability over this micro-optimization unless it's a super-critical piece of the program, but it's a matter of opinion, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In original code behavior is well defined, since operator `||` evaluates first argument and if this is evaluated to false evaluates second argument.

BUT: Assignment there is confusing and many (probably all) static analyzes tools will complain about this. So I would reflector this code in this way, so it would require less brain power to read:

```cpp
void doSomeStuff(const std::set<int>& my_set, int linked_element)
{
    .....
}

void myFunction (const std::set<int>& my_set)
{
    if (my_set.find(firstIndex) != my_set.end())
    {
        doSomeStuff(my_set, firstIndex);
    } else if (my_set.find(secondIndex) != my_set.end()) {
        doSomeStuff(my_set, secondIndex);
    }
}
```

Since you had to ask question about this code this proves that original version is bad from maintainer point of view. Code which requires lots of focus to understand is costly in maintenance.

BTW this fragment of code:

```cpp
if (my_map[linked_element = firstIndex] != 0
```

looks suspicious. I have even more suspensions seeing set-version.
This looks like that someone do not understand how operator[] works for maps. If value for key do not exist, default value is introduced to map. So checking for default value `0` seem like attempt to adders this issue. Possibly `my_map.count(firstIndex)` should be used.

Comment: I'm guessing the main point of writing in the original style was a micro-optimization to avoid the assignment and the `find` call on `secondIndex` if `firstIndex` is found. With this refactor you're achieving that, but adding another function call which didn't exist in the original code. A guess a compiler might inline this call, but if not it may be noticeable.

Comment: Yes, my point was to show code how to make it more clear. I've posted some text since dry code is not welcome on SO. I think this assignment in `if` was to avoid code duplication, so introducing a function IMHO is better approach.

Comment: Oh, agreed. I'd much prefer a function written like this than the original snippet

Answer (score 0):

An alternate version, assuming `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` are literal values (like `2` and `7`), or are otherwise known relative to some invalid third index value:

```
void myFunction (std::set<int> & my_set)
{
    int linked_element =
        my_set.contains (firstIndex)  ? firstIndex  :
        my_set.contains (secondIndex) ? secondIndex :
        thirdIndex;
    if (linked_element != thirdIndex)
    {
        // do some stuff with linked_element
    }
}
```

If the indices are not known then a `std::optional<int>` can step in here too.

If pre-C++20, replace `.contains()` with `.count()`.

Bigger concerns with the original code are:

- the pass-by-value of a potentially large container (never assume COW)
- map[index] silently *adds* the index to the map if not present